# java.io.FileNotFoundException: [WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In`/src/main/java/com/application/myGoogleAppEngine/controller/AddressController.java`, I want to use this instructions for using the beans by after :

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml");
```

My `spring-servlet.xml` file sits in `/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/` directory.

When I execute my spring application, I've the following error :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

In my memories, I know that we can use a function to obtain the current directory of the project but I don't remember.

Otherwise, do you have any solutions ?

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

The `WEB-INF` directory is not typically put on the classpath. Therefore you won't be able to get anything within it as a resource, ie. what `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` is trying to do.

Put your `spring-servlet.xml` in a directory that is put on the classpath, ie. `WEB-INF/classes`.

Comment: How to add a folder into the classpath with eclipse ?

Comment: @user2274060 Add it to a folder that is a source folder. If you are using maven, that's `src/main/resources`.

Answer (score 1):

use this way

new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "classpath*:**/servlet.xml")

This will search whole WEB-INF folder for given name

Answer (score 0):

you can check the web.xml location. If this is not correct it will throw an error.

you can check in properties of the project: please see in the attached image

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLwsi.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdY09.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).